# installing eclipse + dltk 3.0 on windows

Tags: eclipse, dltk

Can someone provide instructions on how to install eclipse + [DLTK 3.0](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/downloads/drops/R3.0/S-3.0.1-201108261011/) on windows? I can only find 2.0 in the Help/Install New Software... area, and installing it manually is confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only seeing version 2.0, you may be using Eclipse 3.6 or earlier version. The latest release, Eclipse Indigo, has access to DLTK 3.0 in the install manager.

The update site adress is `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo`

Once you connect to that update site, you will find the DLTK components in the list. I turned off "Group items by category" and scrolled down to "Dynamic languages ..", then just add the ones you are intrested in.

So a step-by-step instruction in case you are new to Eclipse:

- Go to "window" -> "install new software."
- In the new dialog, click add button.
- Enter location = "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo", click ok.
- Select the new update site from the drop down menu and select the features you need.

Note the dependencies listed on the DLTK webpage, you must install those components first.

Not entirely sure what problems you were having, but this should help you get started. Let me know if you are still having issues.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, that helped me out a lot.